# Creating dynamic DIV in asp .net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I am creating DIVs dynamically which will fetch data from my sql table(from each row) and will show it in DIVs. What problem I am facing is, it only shows the last row of my sql table in a div form
Here is the html

```
<div ID = "containerDiv" class="container" runat = "server">
  <div ID = "columnDiv" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" runat = "server">
     <div ID = "textDiv" class="text" runat="server">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and here is the cs code

```
static int count = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProducts"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    columnDiv.ID = "columnDiv" + count;
                    textDiv.ID = "textDiv" + count;
                    string name = rdr["prod_name"].ToString();
                    string price = rdr["prod_price"].ToString();


                    textDiv.InnerHtml = name + "   " + price;

                    columnDiv.Controls.Add(textDiv);

                    containerDiv.Controls.Add(columnDiv);
                    count++;
                }
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: Are you using **ASP.NET** `WebForms`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `Repeater`, like this ([here's the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <div ID="containerDiv" class="container" runat = "server">
              <div ID="columnDiv" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" runat = "server">
                  <div ID="textDiv" class="text" runat="server">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And supply a `DataSource` in the code behind on the server, and add `'<%# Eval("ColumnName") %>'` expressions in the markup where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to use a GridView:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx